# Is it possible to install Windows APPS (Specifically, Xbox Console Companion) using Wine or an equivalent?

Tags: command-line, wine

[Photo of the Xbox Console Companion App on Microsoft's website.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtJFe.png)

I'm attempting to install the console companion to Ubuntu for a number of reasons. My main one, however, is because I run Ubuntu on an iMac that doesn't have an HDMI port. I own an Xbox and would like to use my iMac as a monitor so I can play through the app's no latency streaming.

Comment: That is a question for wine. Does it support what you want to do? I do not see any thing that has to do with Ubuntu. Wine and Mac questions.

Answer (score 1):

Some applications work.

Some applications don't.

See https://appdb.winehq.org/ for the list of reported applications that have been tested with Wine.